# Does the C++ standard library have a set ordered by insertion order?

Tags: c++, stl, set, std

Does the C++ standard library have an "ordered set" datastructure? By ordered set, I mean something that is exactly the same as the ordinary `std::set` but that remembers the order in which you added the items to it.

If not, what is the best way to simulate one? I know you could do something like have a set of pairs with each pair storing the number it was added in and the actual value, but I dont want to jump through hoops if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: So you want to be able to access it quickly both in sorted order and in insertion order?

Comment: What, precisely, are the other characteristics of `set` you are interested in? Uniqueness? Removal performance?

Comment: @Jefromi I want to quickly tell if an item is in the set and iterate it in inserted order if possible.

Comment: What you're describing is the _exact_ scenario Boost.MultiIndex was created for (see @KerrekSB's answer).

Comment: @Rob uniqueness and speed of checking if something is in the set or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No single, homogeneous data structure will have this property, since it is either sequential (i.e. elements are arranged in insertion order) or associative (elements are arranged in some order depending on value).

The best, clean approach would perhaps be something like [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/), which allows you to add multiple indexes, or "views", on a container, so you can have a sequential and an ordered index.

Comment: +1 for recommending Boost.MultiIndex -- it really is the best solution to these sorts of questions.

Comment: You could use a lambda for the comparison function when initializing the set.  He wants uniqueness of elements but in order of insertion.  I think this may be doable?  I don't understand why this would be prohibited.

Comment: Maybe use a vector and the unique algorithm to remove non unique elements.  Or is this slower than the other methods?  I guess a search algoithm would be slower than simply storing the index.

Comment: @dylan: Yes, but that wouldn't be a single container. You can create any behaviour imaginable with an array and algorithms (computer memory is just one big array)...

Comment: This is incorrect. You could have a BST with the values inserted only relative to other values.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of making a std::set of whatever type you're using, why not pass it a std::pair of the object and an index that gets incremented at each insertion?

Comment: That would sort of work, if you took good care when inserting existing values, and if you somehow had a policy how to find the biggest index in constant time. Perhaps a `std::map<T, unsigned int>` would be slightly more elegant, as its value type is already a pair (and you get mutable mapped elements).

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Mind you, you still have to be able to find the highest current index, and that may not actually be possible in constant, or even logarithmic time.

Comment: @Kerrek why? If you start from 0 (which I am) you can use `map::size` to find the largest index right?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yes, indeed, you could use `size()`, I hadn't thought of that!

Comment: Kerrek's other answer is still better in general, since Boost.MultiIndex will let you *efficiently* access the container indexed by insertion order. As things stand with this `map<T, unsigned int>`, it's an `O(n)` operation to find the element with a given index. Iterating in insertion order is `O(n^2)` with no additional memory, or `O(n log n)` with `O(n)` additional memory if you copy the whole lot into an array and sort before iterating. Might be fine for Seth's purposes, but quite restrictive...

Comment: @KerrekSB The OP seems to indicate he **only** wants iteration by _insertion order_. So a solution for `took good care when inserting existing values` would be great.
I might take to provide a seperate answer for that.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not.

Such a container presumably would need two different iterators, one to iterate in the order defined by the order of adding, and another to iterate in the usual `set` order. There's nothing of that kind in the standard libraries.

One option to simulate it is to have a `set` of some type that contains an intrusive linked list node in addition to the actual data you care about. After adding an element to the `set`, append it to the linked list. Before removing an element from the `set`, remove it from the linked list. This is guaranteed to be OK, since pointers to set elements aren't invalidated by any operation other than removing that element.

Comment: Ah, too bad. What do you recommend doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the answer is fairly simple, combine set with another iteratable structure (say, queue). If you like to iterate the set in the order that the element been inserted, push the elements in queue first, do your work on the front element, then pop out, put into set.

Answer (score 0):

*[Disclaimer: I have given a similar answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942783/need-stl-set-in-insertion-order/55904785) already]*

If you can use Boost, a very straightforward solution is to use the header-only library [Boost.Bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) (bidirectional maps).

Consider the following sample program that will display some dummy entries in insertion order ([try out here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e34e8c9e736b0f7b)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

using namespace std::string_literals;

template <typename T>
void insertByOrder(boost::bimap<T, size_t>& mymap, const T& element) {
  using pos = typename std::remove_reference<decltype(mymap)>::type::value_type;
  // We use size() as index, therefore indexing the elements with 0, 1, ...
  mymap.insert(pos(element, mymap.size()));
}

int main() {
  boost::bimap<std::string, size_t> mymap;

  insertByOrder(mymap, "stack"s);
  insertByOrder(mymap, "overflow"s);

  // Iterate over right map view (integers) in sorted order
  for (const auto& rit : mymap.right) {
    std::cout << rit.first << " -> " << rit.second << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The funky type alias in `insertByOrder()` is needed to insert elements into a `boost::bimap` in the following line (see referenced documentation).

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it's called a vector or list (or array). Just appends to the vector to add element to the set.

Comment: Yeah, but all of those allow for redundant elements, which is most likely what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: pg1989 is correct, I dont want duplicate elements and I dont want to linear search the array to check.