# need STL set in insertion order

Tags: c++, stl, set

How to store elements in set in insertion order.
for example.

```
set<string>myset;

myset.insert("stack");
myset.insert("overflow");
```

If you print, the output is

```
overflow
stack
```

needed output :

```
stack
overflow
```

Comment: could you provide a it more detail?

Comment: what you need is `#include <unordered_set> //std::unordered_set<std::string>`

Comment: @SSpoke that's wrong. Even if one didn't know what an _unordered_ set is, the name already suggests that it cannot possibly be a solution :-)

Answer (score 20):

One way is to use two containers, a `std::deque` to store the elements in insertion order, and another `std::set` to make sure there are no duplicates.

When inserting an element, check if it's in the `set` first, if yes, throw it out; if it's not there, insert it both in the `deque` and the `set`.

One common scenario is to insert all elements first, then process(no more inserting), if this is the case, the `set` can be freed after the insertion process.

Answer (score 6):

A `set` is the wrong container for keeping insertion order, it will sort its element according to the sorting criterion and forget the insertion order. You have to use a sequenced container like vector, deque or list for that. If you additionally need the associative access `set` provides you would have to store your elements in multiple containers simultaneously or use a non-STL container like [boost::multi_index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) which can maintain multiple element orders at the same time.

PS: If you sort the elements before inserting them in a set, the set will keep them in insertion order but I think that will not address your problem.

If you don't need any order besides the insertion order, you could also store the insert number in the stored element and make that the sorting criterion. However, why one would use a set in this case at all escapes me. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I do it:

```
template <class T>
class VectorSet
{
public:
  using iterator                     = typename vector<T>::iterator;
  using const_iterator               = typename vector<T>::const_iterator;
  iterator begin()                   { return theVector.begin(); }
  iterator end()                     { return theVector.end(); }
  const_iterator begin() const       { return theVector.begin(); }
  const_iterator end() const         { return theVector.end(); }
  const T& front() const             { return theVector.front(); }
  const T& back() const              { return theVector.back(); }
  void insert(const T& item)         { if (theSet.insert(item).second) theVector.push_back(item); }
  size_t count(const T& item) const  { return theSet.count(item); }
  bool empty() const                 { return theSet.empty(); }
  size_t size() const                { return theSet.size(); }
private:
  vector<T> theVector;
  set<T>    theSet;
};
```

Of course, new forwarding functions can be added as needed, and can be forwarded to whichever of the two data structures implements them most efficiently. If you are going to make heavy use of STL algorithms on this (I haven't needed to so far) you may also want to define member types that the STL expects to find, like value_type and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Boost, a very straightforward solution is to use the header-only library [Boost.Bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) (bidirectional maps).

Consider the following sample program that will display your dummy entries in insertion order ([try out here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e34e8c9e736b0f7b)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>

using namespace std::string_literals;

template <typename T>
void insertCallOrdered(boost::bimap<T, size_t>& mymap, const T& element) {
  // We use size() as index, therefore indexing with 0, 1, ... 
  // as we add elements to the bimap.
  mymap.insert({ element, mymap.size() });
}

int main() {
  boost::bimap<std::string, size_t> mymap;

  insertCallOrdered(mymap, "stack"s);
  insertCallOrdered(mymap, "overflow"s);

  // Iterate over right map view (integers) in sorted order
  for (const auto& rit : mymap.right) {
    std::cout << rit.first << " -> " << rit.second << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm just wondering why nobody has suggested using such a nice library as Boost MultiIndex. Here's an example how to do that:

```cpp
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>

#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using my_set = boost::multi_index_container<
    T,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::sequenced<>,
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<T>>
    >
>;

int main() {
    my_set<int> set;
    set.push_back(10);
    set.push_back(20);
    set.push_back(3);
    set.push_back(11);
    set.push_back(1);
    
    // Prints elements of the set in order of insertion.
    const auto &index = set.get<0>();
    for (const auto &item : index) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }

    // Prints elements of the set in order of value.
    std::cout << "\n";
    const auto &ordered_index = set.get<1>();
    for (const auto &item : ordered_index) {
        std::cout << item << " ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

what you need is this, very simple and a standard library. Example online compiler link: http://cpp.sh/7hsxo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set> 
static std::unordered_set<std::string> myset;


int main()
{
    myset.insert("blah");
    myset.insert("blah2");
    myset.insert("blah3");

    int count = 0;
    for ( auto local_it = myset.begin(); local_it!= myset.end(); ++local_it ) {
          printf("index: [%d]: %s\n", count,  (*local_it).c_str());
          count++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < myset.bucket_count(); ++i) {
        for ( auto local_it = myset.begin(i); local_it!= myset.end(i); ++local_it )
              printf("bucket: [%d]: %s\n", i,  (*local_it).c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: unordered set , stores element in random order , then how it solves the problem??